# type mismatch using Options in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am very much new to scala and trying to create the function with "Option".I have a function as below which is creating dataframe if required parquet file is present at "Path" 
otherwise need to throw error  :

```
  def getFeeds(sqlContext,Path: String): Either[Throwable, DataFrame] = {
     import sc.spark.implicits._
    try  {
         Right(sc.spark.read.parquet(Path))
     }
     catch {
      case e: ControlThrowable => throw e
      case e: Throwable => {
        log.error("getFeeds failed while reading the data ${Path}", e)
        Left(e)
      }
    }
  }
```

i have another function(resultFeeds) which is expecting dataframe from the above(getFeeds) and I am doing like this:

```
 val Feeds = getFeeds(sc,Path)
    var message = ""
    if (Feeds.isLeft) message = s"${message}Feeds:missing;"

    Feeds match {
        case Right(a) =>
              val df = resultFeeds(sc, a)
              case Left(_) => log.error("skipping lookup.Metrics due to internal error")
              dbObj.writeToPostgres(df, "lookup.Metrics")
             "Data Loaded into the db"
          }
        }
```

resultFeed is dumping the dataframe into postgres .However,when I am trying to run the above code then detting the error as :

```
  found   : Unit
[error]     required : TestClass.this.output
               (which expands to)  String
[error]               case Right(a) =>
[error]                             ^
[error]                 not found: value df
[error]                   dbObj.writeToPostgres(df, "lookup.Metrics")
```

Please help me !!

Answer (score 2):

The code for your pattern matching is off:

```
feeds match {
  case Right(a) => 
    val df = resultFeeds(sc, a)
    dbObj.writeToPostgres(df, "lookup.Metrics")
    "Data Loaded into the db"
  case Left(_) => log.error("skipping lookup.Metrics due to internal error")
}
```

In addition, let me show an additional approach to the above code:

```
def getFeeds(sqlContext: SparkSession ,Path: String): Either[Throwable, DataFrame] = {
    import sc.spark.implicits._
    Try(sc.spark.read.parquet(Path)).toEither
}
```

And then:

```
val dfOrFailure = getFeeds(sc, path).map(df => resultFeeds(sc, df))
dfOrFailure match {
  case Right(df) => dbObj.writeToPostgres(df, "lookup.Metrics")
  case Left(err) => log.error("Failed to fetch feed", err)
}
```

Note that if `resultFeeds` itself returns an `Either[Throwable, A]` you can continue chaining the execution, perhaps more clearly with a for comprehension:

```
def resultFeeds(sc: SparkContext, a: ???): Either[Throwable, DataFrame] = ???

val finalDf = for {
  dfFeed <- getFeeds(sc, path)
  res    <- resultFeeds(sc, dfFeed)
} yield res

finalDf match {
  case Right(df) => dbObj.writeToPostgres(df, "lookup.Metrics")
  case Left(err) => log.error("Failed to fetch feed", err)
}
```